# How do I acknowledge collisions with volumes in UDK?

Tags: udk

As part of creating a stealth system, I've decided to place volumes over light sources as a first step. The idea being that when a pawn walks into one of those volumes, it will be logged.

How can I detect and react to collisions between a pawn and these sorts of volumes?

Comment: Did you try placing a pawn is one of those volumes and running that a debugger (not sure you can really debug Unreal Script, but you could just do some printf debugging)?